# How to stop xfce from full-screening a window when dragging the title bar and it hits the top of the screen?

Tags: xfce

When I am trying to position a window against the top of the screen, as the mouse get within a few pixels of the top , the window flips to full screen size, which is totally annoying. The<same on the left and right edges, making the window full-height. Is there a way to disable this behaviour? I've searched the Settings menu items, the web and the XFCE docs with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Window Manager Tweaks, go to its Accessibility tab, and uncheck "Automatically tile windows when moving toward the screen edge".